# How do I get a user information from YouTube API V3 without using OAuth?

Tags: python, oauth, youtube-data-api, userinfo

I'm trying to get user account details by using YouTube API V3

I can get the channel details without oauth. But now, I want to know user account details(email, profile) from YouTube without using oauth process

So, here is the scopes for getting user information:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

My question is: Is there any way to retrieve user account details from YouTube without Oauth process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Is there any way to retrieve user account details from YouTube without Oauth process?

No absolutely not.

What you need to understand is the difference between public and private data.

You may be able to get a YouTube channel details without being authorized this is because this is public data. You can also search for YouTube videos with the api without being authorized this is again public data.

A users profile information is NOT public data. This is private user data owned by the user.  If you want to access a users profile information then you need to use Oauth2 and request the users consent for your application accessing their data.